# Any self-hosted Firebase alternatives?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I just recently discovered Firebase, and watched a video of how Firebase can complement AngularJS application. I was super excited, right until I realized, that Firebase only available as a hosted service, and as such, is not an option for my employer.
I'd like to ask if anyone is aware of a framework or a library, offering a comparable feature set (i.e. auto-binded madel back-end persistence combined with a real-time push)
Any information would be great.

Comment: You could create your own version with a service that opens a socket, and broadcasts angular events when it gets data.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that, just wanted to see if there is a readily reusable JS library available.

Comment: Firebase also includes a huge data storage component, making them more of a solution for customers looking for a complete server side solution. In my case however I'm really only interested in the real time events handling. As you scale your number of connections, data store increase and have I no need for terabytes of data storage. Firebase is very cool though and has great libraries for RoR and AngularJS. Firebase is also great because you don't need to do any server management.

Comment: 2 other Firebase type services include http://www.pubnub.com/ and https://pusher.com/

Comment: Firebase offers data-sync whereas pubnub and pusher are publish-subscribe services. A closer self hosted alternative would be https://deepstream.io/

Comment: You can check SapphireDB, https://sapphire-db.com/start/main , please take a look to the browser support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found my answer - [meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/). Has a host of amazing features including realtime data

Answer (score 3):

I recently discovered [Deployd](http://deployd.com/). For most use cases, this should work nicely.

Comment: Deployd is no longer maintained https://github.com/deployd/deployd

Answer (score 2):

Most of my backend-less learning comes from [NoBackend](http://nobackend.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also socketcluster: http://socketcluster.io/
It's not a framework - More like a realtime environment. You can run various Node.js frameworks like express on top of it.

Comment: Socketcluster does not seem to be a data store. How can it substitute for Firebase?

Comment: @sax You can hook up your own datastore/database in the backend. It acts like a realtime layer between your front end and your database (more setup time, extra flexibility). You have to publish data changes yourself. A good pattern is to have URL-like (REST) channels like '/student/123/' so when someone updates that model, you can publish the data to that channel from the backend directly after adding it to the database.